# Is there an siunitx number formatting option equivalent to pgfplots's "fixed relative"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, siunitx

I need to typeset a table with units, so I'd like to use `siunitx` for that. However, I don't want scientific notation, but a given number of figures. `pgfplots` has the `fixed relative` option for that purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\def\numA{1.23456789e3}
\def\numB{1.23456789e-3}
\begin{document}
\noindent
  pgf standard format:\\
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\numA}\\
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\numB}\\
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed relative,precision=3}
  desired format:\\
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\numA}\\
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\numB}
\end{document}
```

This is the output of the above code:

[image]

I'd like to get the same output with `siunitx`, if possible. I've tried explicitly disabling `scientific-notation`, but as it seems that key is only useful for enabling scientific notation when `siunitx` would otherwise *not* use it:

```
\num{\numA}\\
\num{\numB}\\
\sisetup{round-mode=figures,round-precision=3,scientific-notation=false}
\num{\numA}\\
\num{\numB}\
```

Output:

[image]

One possibility would be to redefine `\SI{}{}` and `\num{}` to use `\pgfmathprintnumber{}` and disabling `siunitx`'s number parsing, but I'd like to know what else I could do.

My current workaround is:

```
\let\oldnum\num
\renewcommand{\num}[1]{\oldnum[parse-numbers=false]{\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}}
\let\oldSI\SI
\renewcommand{\SI}[3][]{\oldSI[#1,parse-numbers=false]{\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}{#3}}
```

but this doesn't let me pass options to `\pgfmathprintnumber`. Passing options to `\SI` works well, as in `\SI[per-mode=fraction]{1e-3}{\meter\per\second}`.

Comment: Do you mean rounding to a number of significant figures?

Comment: Yes, rounding is a part of the problem. My numbers come from an external file with 19 figures each and I want to round them to a fixed number of significant figures, but without scientific notation.

Comment: At present, I suspect the answer in 'no',but work on v2.5 is due to take place over the next week. So I will look into this.

Comment: @Joseph: Thank you! I've added my current workaround, not sure if that is helpful to others but it works for me despite all its limitations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible in version 2.5, which deals correctly with fixed exponent of zero

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\def\numA{1.23456789e3}
\def\numB{1.23456789e-3}
\begin{document}
\noindent
  pgf standard format:\\
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\numA}\\
  \num{\numA}\\
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\numB}\\
  \num{\numB}\\
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed relative,precision=3}
  \sisetup{scientific-notation = fixed, fixed-exponent = 0, round-mode = figures,
    round-precision = 3}
  desired format:\\
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\numA}\\
  \num{\numA}\\
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\numB}\\
  \num{\numB}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: CTAN update over the weekend!

Comment: bazinga! Thank you! That makes life much easier.